# Are there pure virtual functions in PHP like with C++

Tags: php, pure-virtual

I would have thought lots of people would have wondered whether this is possible but I can't find any duplicate questions... do correct me.

I just want to know whether PHP offers pure virtual functions.  I want the following

```
class Parent {
   // no implementation given
   public function foo() {
      // nothing 
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   public function foo() {
      // implementation of foo goes here
   }
}
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create abstract functions, but you need to declare the parent class as abstract, too:

```
abstract class Parent {
   // no implementation given
   abstract public function foo();
}

class Child extends Parent {
   public function foo() {
      // implementation of foo goes here
   }
}
```

Comment: A pure virtual function requires that is defined in a sub-class.  If not an error should occur.  Will an error occur if foo() is not defined.  This is key.

Comment: Yes, if you extend `Parent` but do not define `foo` you will get an error (unless your subclass is also abstract, in which case it cannot be instantiated and any non-abstract subclasses must define `foo` themselves). For more information, see [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), which states that "all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child".

Comment: And when a class is declared `abstract` does it mean all it's functions must be `abstract` (that is, `pure virtual`), or you may create virtual and final functions (I mean functions not prepended with the `abstract` keyword)?

Comment: @Silidrone An abstract class may have abstract or concrete functions.  See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Declare the method as abstract in the Parent class:

```
abstract public function foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are [abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)!

```
abstract class Parent {
   // no implementation given
   abstract public function foo();
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   public function foo() {
      // implementation of foo goes here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that type of solution is possible, it's called polymorphism, you can do it without declaring an abstract class or an interface.

Comment: Creating an empty method without declaring the method as abstract (like in the question) does not reflect C++ pure-virtual method behaviour (which is the same as abstract methods in PHP).

Comment: This is the best answer in the world for anything ever. I hope that one day when my kids grow up I can show them this answer and they can be impressed as much as I am right now. Generations of programmers are better because of it, you probably single handedly saved millions of lives here - well done sir, well done. Have a +1.